# Force cloning slides in slick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, slick.js

I have a needed that I've not been able to develop.

I'm using slick to show 3 slides, but only the center one shows all the information. I need an infinite slider in order to get all the slides being at the center.

The problem is when the slides are only 3, because it stops. I would need to force the slider clonning the slides as if i had 4 or more slides...

```
      $('.center').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '0px',
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        adaptiveHeight: true

        });
```

Here I leave you an example with slides enough: https://jsfiddle.net/f580ys4b/1/

And here an example with only 3 slides: https://jsfiddle.net/f580ys4b/2/

Answer (score 2):

Before initiating Slick, check if the number of slide items is larger than slidesToShow. In case it is not, duplicate the children until there are more slide items than slides to show. Can easily be done with jQuery.

```
var slideCount = jQuery(".slide").length;
if (slideCount <= 3) {
  // clone element
  jQuery(".center.slider").children().clone(true, true).appendTo(".center.slider");
}

jQuery('.center').slick({
  arrows: false,
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '0px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  dots: false,
  focusOnSelect: true,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I've finally done, but in responsive the final project will show dots, I'm not sure that the client will accept the solution. Crossing fingers...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My solution based on Rohan answer:

In my case I have a slider with filters, when the filtered elements are the same as the elements to be displayed, the infinite dont working. When I reset the slider when filtering I compare the filtered elements with those that should be displayed and if they are equal I duplicate the elements.

```
$('.slider-productos').on('reInit', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    // total sliders number  -   get option slidesToShow number
    //            ^                    ^
    if (slick.slideCount === slick.options.slidesToShow) {

        // you can clone on slider or all, it depends on how many slider you want to show
        //var toClone = $(".slider-productos .slick-track").children('.slick-slide:nth-of-type(2)');
        var toClone1 = $(".slider-productos .slick-track").children('.slick-slide:nth-of-type(1)');
        var toClone2 = $(".slider-productos .slick-track").children('.slick-slide:nth-of-type(2)');
        var toClone3 = $(".slider-productos .slick-track").children('.slick-slide:nth-of-type(3)');

        toClone1.clone().appendTo(".slider-productos .slick-track");
        toClone2.clone().appendTo(".slider-productos .slick-track");
        toClone3.clone().appendTo(".slider-productos .slick-track");

        // Set any option only for refresh slider                        refresh true
        //                            ^                                    ^
        $('.slider-productos').slick('slickSetOption', 'infinite', true, true);
    }

});
```